# Creating a Web Service to automatically get information

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, web-services

I want to create some sort of method of creating a web service that will run automatically and run DB queries and some API calls which will then store data that I can use/call without taking the processing or time penalty of doing it every time a user access my web service. Is this possible? If so, point me in the right direction on how to implement something like this

Using vb.net and ASP.net

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

After you create your Web Service you can implement caching of the data.

You can follow the MSDN guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647786.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to have the functions already executed on the server, and hold the data in advance so when I call it, the processing has already been done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the proxy and caching design patterns.